# How do I get the TOP 1 value from a UNION of 2 columns?

Tags: sql-server

This is the query, how do I select the top 1 from the result? This is for SQL Server.

```
SELECT column1 
FROM table 
WHERE column2 = 'Whatever' AND column3 = 'Sure'

UNION

SELECT column4 
FROM table 
WHERE column2 = 'Whatever' AND column3 = 'Sure'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM
(
  SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE column2 = 'Whatever' AND column3 = 'Sure'
  UNION
  SELECT column4 FROM table WHERE column2 = 'Whatever' AND column3 = 'Sure'
) R
ORDER BY Column1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT max(Column) FROM (
  SELECT column1 as Column FROM table WHERE ....
  UNION 
  SELECT column4 as Column FROM table WHERE ....
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM (
    SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE column2 = 'Whatever' AND column3 = 'Sure'
    UNION
    SELECT column4 FROM table WHERE column2 = 'Whatever' AND column3 = 'Sure')
```